# Rails 4 - Why do index records remain after destroy_all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I have a user model in my rails 4 app.

I have gone into my console and done:

```
User.destroy_all
```

User.count verifies to me that there are no users. I then try to sign up again, which I am allowed to do, but once I confirm my email and try to sign in, I get an error that says:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_email"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=(angus@gmail.com) already exists.
```

How can I fix this index records so that those are also deleted when the User.destroy_all method is run?

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: it is because of sequence .. reset your table squence `ALTER SEQUENCE "your_sequence_name" RESTART WITH 0;`

Comment: Can you show migration for users table?

Comment: @uzaif what does that mean? I just destroy_all in the console and I expect everything to go. Do you mean I then need to login to psql and change the table?

Answer (score -1):

To ensure you don't have this problem, make sure you delete all the relevant data when destroying a User.

```
class UpdateUserForeignKey < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_foreign_key :users, :email

    add_foreign_key :users, :email, on_delete: :cascade
  end
end
```

More about Rails Foreign Keys
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_foreign_key

Comment: Hello Vlad. I think maybe our wires are crossed. I tried to use the console to destroy all records in the user table. Something has been preserved because whilst I expect the table to be empty, i get the error above, indicating that something has been retained. I don't want to write migrations to change the table.